# How to add padding outside of a btn in css?

Tags: html, css

```html
<li>
  <a class="btn btn-primary py-2 px-2 d-inline-block theme_button" href="">Click me</a>
</li>
```

I have this code and this button is touching the `div`, I have tried putting `padding: 10px;` but it still touches the `div`.

Comment: Best to post a live demo, as there are so many classes there potentially affecting the styling.

Comment: `padding` is space between the border and the inner content. You're looking for `margin`

Comment: @slebetman oh right thank you I was confused with padding and margin

Comment: @dinays next time, Try posting expected results like photos; it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be 100% sure without seeing more details on the code you've written, but if there isn't other styling affecting your layout, changing padding to margin should do the trick.